# Having trouble linking to file using relative path

Tags: include

I’ve created a widget plugin and have placed the code for displaying the front end content in a separate file. I’m linking to the file using `include_once` but keep getting the error, `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...`
The plugin folder contains 2 subfolders: `includes` and `tpls` The file I’m linking to is in the `tpls` folder and I’m linking to it from the `includes` folder.
This is the code I’m using to link to the file:

```
// Creating widget front-end
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

include_once('../tpls/frontend.php' );
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to have a forward slash before `tpls` but I tried it both ways and I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by using `include_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/../tpls/frontend.php');`
The file I'm using `include_once` in is itself included from the `index.php` file in the plugin's root directory so, according to the documentation on the subject, a relative path to the file will be relative to the root directory, not the `inc` folder.
However, in that case I expected to be able to include the file like this: `include_once('./tpls/frontend.php');` but after testing it I found it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: while it ends up being the same, there is also an API to get your "current" directory https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/